# jackson infinite recursion on a node class with self reference

Tags: java, json, tree, jackson

I am having an issue using jackson writeValueAsString, on a class that acts as a node class with references to parent and child throughout.

```
public Node<T>{
     private T key;

     private List<Node<T>> children;

     private Node<T> parent;
}
```

when I construct this it ends up being a hierarchal structure of these node objects with references to its relative children at each layer, but also a reference to the parent.

```
Node@111:
   children:
        Node@222:
          children:
              Node@333: children
                 ...etc
              parent: 
                 Node@222
           parent: Node@111
```

everything about this is working nicely in my business logic but I would like to output json

I have the following set on the mapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_SELF_REFERENCES, false);
    String json = "";
    try {
       json = mapper.writeValueAsString(nodeImpl);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       // logging
    }
    return json;
```

I am getting the infinite recursion error due to this object

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: io.tychon.common.model.Node["children"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->io.moobyworld.model....
```

so I have tried adding

```
@JsonManagedReference
private Node<T> parent;

@JsonBackReference
private List<Node<T>> children;
```

didn't help so I tried switching the Managed and Back References since children are a collection. I don't even need the parent property in the json so I also tried

```
@JsonIgnore
private Node<T> parent;
```

None of what I have been able to find seems to help this scenario. Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use? Could you create a simple example which does not work for you? I used only one annotation `@JsonBackReference private Node<T> parent;` with version `2.9.9` and it works fine: `{"key":"ROOT","children":[{"key":"C0","children":[]},{"key":"C1","children":[]}]}`

Comment: 2.10...I have tried that single annotation on parent and still yields the same error?

Comment: Could you create a simple structure of `Node<String>` nodes and try it out? Maybe you use some complex types and this is why it does not work for you.